# Regex: Match expression only once it a line

Tags: regex, regex-greedy

I'm trying to match only the first instance of ": " in a line of text that may have 1 or more occurrences.

Example content:

```
title: This is a title: This is a subtitle
```

So I only want to match the ": " after "title"

I've tried this:

```
/(: ?)/
```

But it matches all of them still.

I know it needs to be non-greedy using the ? but so far it seems to just be non-greedy while still matching numerous occurrences in a given line.

Thank for any help :)

#### UPDATE 20160823 @ 13:50

The following is an example of the content I'm parsing:

```
root
    parent
        title: The title with (: ) to be ignored
        text: A line of text
```

So the ": "  will most likely be preceded by indentation and the word before the first ": " could be anything.

#### Solution @ 27/01/2017

So this seems to be working:

```
$text = "    title: Page: Website - Tagline";
preg_match("~^(?:[\t ]+)*(?:([\w]+)(?:: ){1})([\s\S]+)$~", $text, $matches);

$matches[1]; // title
$matches[2]; // Page: Website - Tagline
```

Comment: Both colons (": ") come after "title".

Comment: Show the code where you are using the regex. Or what tool you are using

Comment: @Rawing, that will not allow extracting the text from `Text:title: text2 subtitle`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `(?m)^(?:(?!: ).)*(: )`

Comment: @Rawing Yes, a tempered greedy token is the correct choice, but it is a pity OP keeps silent. I do not like these complex constructions. There might be a better solution.

Comment: Sorry, had to go for lunch. So I'm using PHP preg_match if that helps. But I've been testing things out in http://regexr.com

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Please provide the expected result for the input you have. It is not a rocket science to match the first cilon and spaces with `preg_match('#:\s*#', $input, $match)`, but that looks an XY problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
^[^:]*(:).*
```

So ^ marks the beginning of the line,

[^:]* - looks throush the line until it sees colon

(:) - matches the first colon in the line

.* (optional) - the rest of the line

Comment: Doesn't `[^:]` exclude all instances of `:` ?